# Why instantons cannot cause confinement in 4d?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, instantons, confinement

I am reading Aspects of Symmetry by Sidney Coleman. More specifically
I am trying to learn about instantons, and I would like some clarifications.

In chapter 7, section 4. he derives confinement in a 2 dimensional abelian Higgs
model using the dilute instanton gas approximation, and than
argues that such a mechanism cannot possibly work in 4D. He derives
confinement in the sense of the Wilson loop criterion.

If I understand correctly, the important difference, is that
in 2D, instantons deep inside the Wilson loop have a non
negligable contribution to the functional integral, while in 4D
this is not the case, there, only instantons that overlap with the
loop contribute. What I do not understand is what specific properties
of the 4D instanton solutions make this
last statement true. What is the difference between 2D and 4D?

In the 2D model, the Wilson loop  will be simply determined
(at least for large loops) by the winding
number that we would get if we only considered instantons inside
the loop. Such a simple thing cannot be said in 4D where to
get the equivalent of the winding number we would need to
consider a 3D surface integral.

But than again, all this says to me is that I cannot carry out the computation
along the same lines in 4D than what was done in 2D. That does not
necessarily mean, as I quote "Whatever confines quarks, it is not instantons."

Thanks in advance for any clarifications on the matter.

Comment: Think about it like this (very handwavy, hence no answer) - the reason you get the confining "area law" in 2D is that the whole *area* inside the Wilson loop contributes. In 4D, only the overlaps contribute, so you get no area law, hence no confinement.